# Kill individual threads when timeout in a service

Tags: python, flask, timeout

I am building a python flask service for which I am trying to setup a timeout for each individual POST request.
As I understand whenever someone sends a post request to my RESTful service, a new thread (virtual or real) starts executing it.

Now in order for my server to serve a lot of requests I want it to return a TIME-OUT response if a process runs for more than a constant time defined for it (TIMEOUT_TIME) set for each POST method and stop the execution of that individual thread.

Can you propose me an abstract scheme that I could implement, using flask-methods?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to run the request processing in a separate process and terminate it if a timeout is exceeded:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/api/sleep', methods=['POST'])
def sleep():
    duration = int(request.args.get('duration', 1))
    timeout = float(request.args.get('timeout', 2))

    proc = Process(target=process_request, args=(duration,))
    proc.start()
    proc.join(timeout)

    if proc.is_alive():
        proc.terminate()
        proc.join()

        return jsonify(success=False, message='timeout exceeded'), 408

    return jsonify(success=True, message='well done')


def process_request(t):
    time.sleep(t)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

In this example, when a sleep `duration` is less than a given `timeout`, a user will get a successful response:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/sleep?duration=1\&timeout=2
{
  "message": "well done", 
  "success": true
}
```

Otherwise, the user will get `408` error:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/sleep?duration=2\&timeout=1
{
  "message": "timeout exceeded", 
  "success": false
}
```

The problem with this approach is noted in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html)

> Note that exit handlers and finally clauses, etc., will not be executed.

It means that the running processes won't be able to clean up before exiting which might cause problems. Another solution is to use a special `Joiner` thread which will be used to join worker processes or threads later on in the case the timeout is exceeded:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify


class Joiner(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.workers = Queue()

    def run(self):

        while True:
            worker = self.workers.get()

            if worker is None:
                break

            worker.join()


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/api/sleep', methods=['POST'])
def sleep():
    duration = int(request.args.get('duration', 1))
    timeout = int(request.args.get('timeout', 2))

    worker = Thread(target=process_request, args=(duration,))
    worker.start()
    worker.join(timeout)

    if worker.is_alive():
        joiner.workers.put(worker)

        return jsonify(success=False, message='timeout exceeded'), 408

    return jsonify(success=True, message='well done')


def process_request(t):
    time.sleep(t)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    joiner = Joiner()
    joiner.start()

    app.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)

    joiner.workers.put(None)
    joiner.join()
```

Here, before running the flask server a `Joiner` thread instance is created and started. Once the server is stopped, we put `None` into the `joiner.workers` queue to signal the `joiner` thread to finish.